# if conditions in where clause

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I want to retrieve the columns from the table., depending on the conditions.,
what I can use.

For example, I' ve fields namely, add order comments, cancel order comments, postpone order comments, action(add, cancel, postpone) and amount received(Y/N)

Now I've to fetch columns add order comments, cancel order comments, postpone order comments depending on action and amount received.,

```
if(action='add' and amount received='Y')
then
i've to fetch add order comments column
elseif(action='postpone' and amount received='Y')
then
i've to fetch postpone order comments column
else (action='cancel')
then i've to fetch cancel order comments
```

how to get this done in sql or plsql., I want this conditions in select statement

Comment: MySQL, MS SQL-Server, Oracle, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by "sql or plsql" I'm assuming that "sql" refers to T-SQL as used by MS SQL Server. If not, please use the appropriate equivalent in your language.

You need to use a [CASE (T-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement ([PL-SQL equivalent](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php))

For example, in T-SQL:

```
SELECT OrderId AS OrderId
       CASE 
           WHEN Action = 'add' AND amountRcd = 'Y' THEN addOrderComment
           WHEN Action = 'postpont' AND amountRcd = 'Y' THEN postponeOrderComment
           WHEN Action = 'cancel' THEN cancelOrderComment 
           ELSE 'Unrecognised action'
       END AS Comment
FROM tblOrders
```

Note also that in the rules you've given, if the `amountRcd` field is not `Y`, then you will get "Unrecognised action" as the comment. I think you may need to clarify your rules to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select order comment case when action ='add' 
     and amount received ='y'
  else select postpone order comments when action ='postpone'
    and amount received='y'
  else select cancel when action ='cancel' end 
  from table
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, then an alternative way of accomplishing this would be to perform three separate queries and then union them together.

```
select orderID as OrderID, addOrderComments as Comment
from tblOrders
where Action = 'add' AND amountRcd = 'Y'
union 
select orderID as OrderID, postponeOrderComment as Comment
from tblOrders
where Action = 'postpone' AND amountRcd = 'Y'
union
select orderID as OrderID, cancelOrderComment as Comment
from tblOrders
where Action = 'cancel'
```